# Apex | How i can create EmailMessage register in Chatter component of a custom object?

Tags: java, email, salesforce, apex, salesforce-chatter

At de moment we are implement a Email Service in a custom object where we want to received and reply emails but, when we create a EmailMessage register in the Apex class, the register in the chatter component from custom object appear like a task. We want that the EmailMessage register appear like in the Case object.

EmailMessage register in Case object:
[image]

EmailMessage register in the custom object:
[image]

We want to in the custom object appear the EmailMessage register like in the Case object.

How can we solve it?
What are the best prectices?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.